# Maemo: how to get system information/specifications?

Tags: maemo

How can I find the maximum resolution, processor type and RAM capacity of my device in Maemo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a full linux system, so in an xterm you can:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
# cat /proc/meminfo
```

For the resolution, it's 800x480.  But xdpyinfo doesn't exist on the system so I think you need to look in the X log file to get it.

Comment: Can I compile for example FFMPEG there !?

Comment: Well, you can.  I'm not sure why you'd want to since 'apt-cache search ffmpeg' shows me someone else already has!

Comment: I just wanted to see if I can compile there

Comment: There is, but I haven't tried it, a compiler that you can put on the device itself.  I tend to compile on my desktop when compiling for the N900 and the transferring the results there (via scp to it).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Conky](http://www.my-maemo.com/software/applications.php?name=Conky&faq=42&fldAuto=1066). It's a really nice and useful system metrics vizualisation app for Maemo.

[image: Conky 1.8.1 screen]
<sub>(source: [mynokian900.com](http://www.mynokian900.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Conky-1.8.1.png))</sub>